# Как браузер определяет что нужно отправить Keep-Alive?

Tags: http

На моей локальной машине (localhost) при самом первом открытии странички в Request заголовках GET запроса отправляется `Connection: Keep-Alive`, а вот на хостинге этот заголовок не уходит и, соответственно, сервер не отвечает тем же самым `Connection: Keep-Alive`, поэтому соединение закрывается.

Из-за этого если пользователь переходит на другую страницу на сайте и потом нажимает кнопку Назад, то страница на которую он попадает перезагружается, а не остается в том же состоянии что была (с тем же значением скрола, фильтрами и прочее).

Почему в одном случае браузер отправляет Kepp-Alive, а в другом нет? Как это исправить?